# Inserindo informações várias vezes

Tags: array, python-3.x, lógica, for

Boa tarde, estou desenvolvendo um pequeno script para organizar umas informações que estão contidas em um vetor, a ideia é percorrer dois vetores, quando as informações de cada um forem iguais, deve inserir um `\n` e depois o elemento do `VetorUm`.
O `VetorUm` é o principal, o `VetorDois` é só informações para ajudar a colocar o `\n` no lugar certo e se os elementos forem diferentes deve inserir apenas o elemento, porém não sei onde errei já que está inserindo os elementos várias vezes.

Segue o código:

```
for indice , item in enumerate(VetorUm):
    for Contador in range(0, len(VetorDois)):
        if item == NomePlacas[Contador]:
            ResultadoSaida.insert(indice,"\n" + "\n")
        ResultadoSaida.append(item)
```

Exemplo dos vetores:

```
VetorUm = ['este','é','um','vetor','para','exemplo','do','problema','apresentado','na','questão','acima']

VetorDois = ['vetor','problema','questão']

ResultadoSaida = ['este','é','um','\n','vetor','para','exemplo','do','\n','problema','apresentado','na','\n','questão','acima']
```

Comment: E o que está "mais ou menos errado" na sua opinião? Consegue [edit] a pergunta e adicionar exemplos de como seriam o `VetorUm` e `VetorDois` e qual deveria ser a saída gerada?

Comment: É que está inserindo informações cada vez que passa no VetorDois, esse acho que é o erro, farei a edição.

Comment: Gabriel, para o exemplo que colocou na pergunta, qual deveria ser a saída?

Comment: A saída seria o vetor ResultadoSaida.

Comment: A ordem das palavras em `VetorDois` importa? Por exemplo, se em `VetorUm` aparecer a palavra `'problema'` antes da palavra `'vetor'` a quebra deve ser inserida ou não? Isto é, deve inserir porque a palavra percence ao `VetorDois` ou não deve ser inserida porque primeiro deve vir a palavra `'vetor'`?

Comment: A ordem não importa, pois o conteúdo vai variar muito. Sempre que aparecer essas palavras tem que acontecer isso, independente de onde estejam e quantas vezes apareçam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vetorUm = ['este','é','um','vetor','para','exemplo','do','problema','apresentado','na','questão','acima']
vetorDois = ['vetor','problema','questão']
vetorResultado = []

for item1 in vetorUm:
    if item1 in vetorDois:
        vetorResultado.append('\n')
    vetorResultado.append(item1)
print(vetorResultado)
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

A ideia é sempre adicionar uma quebra de linha, `'\n'`, na lista de saída quando for encontrada uma palavra de `VetorUm` que pertence ao `VetorDois`. Então basta fazer um laço percorrendo `VetorUm` e verificar se a palavra está em `VetorDois`:

```py
vetor_um = ['este','é','um','vetor','para','exemplo','do','problema','apresentado','na','questão','acima']
vetor_dois = ['vetor','problema','questão']
resultado = []

for palavra in vetor_um:
  if palavra in vetor_dois:
    resultado.append('\n')
  resultado.append(palavra)

print(resultado)
```

A saída será: `['este', 'é', 'um', '\n', 'vetor', 'para', 'exemplo', 'do', '\n', 'problema', 'apresentado', 'na', '\n', 'questão', 'acima']`

Você poderia inclusive definir uma função que trabalhe com geradores:

```py
def adiciona_quebra_linhas(vetor_um, vetor_dois):
  for palavra in vetor_um:
    if palavra in vetor_dois:
      yield '\n'
    yield palavra
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/JuicyGiddyAutomaticvectorization)</sup>

E assim chamar `adiciona_quebra_linhas(vetor_um, vetor_dois)`, obtendo o mesmo resultado.